# macOS Sierra: Configuring Subversion/SVN on Apache

Tags: macos, vmware, apache, subversion

Every Mac OSX/macOS update brings further challenges to get svn working after the update.  Sierra's the latest.

I have a subversion repo in `~/svnRepo`

I run some windows development stuff in a VM running on `172.16.99.4` which can connect to the Mac host using `http://172.16.99.1`.  I use Tortoise and Visual Studio.

Normally I build the SVN server on the Mac using the current method.  Last time I 'brewed' my own.

Sierra has `subversion` running,  e.g. `terminal> svnadmin info ~/svnRepo` returns info about the repository.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use the native subversion server to serve up subversion to the VM?
2. Must another subversion server be installed and configured on Apache?
3. How can Sierra be configured to connect to my pre-existing repo?
4. Is there  a quick and easy way doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run a native subversion server on your Mac to serve your virtual machines.

If your virtual machines can access services on your Mac, as your question suggests they can, then you can offer a subversion service natively on your Mac.

## svnserve

The easiest approach is to use subversion's standalone server, [`svnserve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html):

> The svnserve program is a lightweight server, capable of speaking to clients over TCP/IP using a custom, stateful protocol. Clients contact an svnserve server by using URLs that begin with the `svn://` or `svn+ssh://` scheme. This section will explain the different ways of running svnserve, how clients authenticate themselves to the server, and how to configure appropriate access control to your repositories.

A copy of `svnserve` is included with Xcode:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svnserve
```

`svnserve` does not require an Apache `httpd` instance or any other server to work. The `svnserve` process listens and handles connections from `svn` clients.

### Security Considerations

You can add tunnelling over `ssh` and other approaches to add security. Without additional configuration, a plain `svnserve` instance is not recommended for exposure to the Internet; it is not secure by default.

However, for your local-only situation `svnserve` is likely enough.

Comment: `svnserve -d -r ~/svnRepo` seems to be just the ticket. Much easier than configuring apache, etc.

Comment: How does one configure the Mac firewall to enable the SVN port (3690)?  - or should I ask another question?

Comment: Good to hear `svnserve` works for you. If you could ask another question about the firewall, you will attract better, more focused, answers.

Comment: Asked this question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259796/macos-sierra-10-12-configure-firewall-for-a-single-port-3690 (my previous link was wrong!)